# Is there any way to use YouTube player iframe with rounded corners? (css, jQuery...)

Tags: jquery, css, youtube, rounded-corners

I would like to use YouTube iframe player in my web which has a white background, and I would like to use the YouTube player with rounded corners. CSS3 doesn't work for this.

Comment: Use the YouTube embedded player: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

How about just using a div with rounded corners and then embedding the you tube player in it like Blender suggests?